# Spring WS Camel | overriding default http connection properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-ws

We are working on performance tuning of camel spring-ws API to support high TPS. we are trying to override default connection properties of HttpComponentsMessageSender with custom spring-webservice template based on below spring-ws doc , but with no luck.

https://camel.apache.org/components/3.15.x/spring-ws-component.html

camel.version -3.0.1
spring-boot-version - 2.6.3

**Camel Route**

```
.doTry()
        .to(dStreamPath)
```

**Spring WS YAML Config**

```
dStreamPath: spring-ws:http://URL/getOffers?webServiceTemplate=#customSpringWSTemplate&amp;soapAction=http://www.url.org
```

**Bean Config**

```
@Bean(name = "customSpringWSTemplate")
   public WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate() throws Exception {
    final MessageFactory msgFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_2_PROTOCOL);
    final SaajSoapMessageFactory saajSoapMessageFactory = new SaajSoapMessageFactory(msgFactory);
    final WebServiceTemplate customSpringWSTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate(saajSoapMessageFactory);
    HttpComponentsMessageSender httpMessageSender = new HttpComponentsMessageSender();
    httpMessageSender.setMaxConnectionsPerHost(new HashMap<String, String>() {
        { put("http://URL/getOffers", "20");}
    });
    httpMessageSender.setMaxTotalConnections(100);

    customSpringWSTemplate.setMessageSender(httpMessageSender);
    return customSpringWSTemplate;
}
```

Error :

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: 
spring-ws://URL due to:
There are 1 parameters that couldn't be set on the endpoint. Check the uri if the parameters are spelt correctly and that they are properties of the endpoint. Unknown parameters=[{amp;soapAction=http://URL}]
    at org.apache.camel.support.DefaultComponent.validateParameters(DefaultComponent.java:199)
    at org.apache.camel.support.DefaultComponent.createEndpoint(DefaultComponent.java:135)
```

Comment: When using Java DSL, you should not escape URI parameters. Try with `&soapAction=...` instead of `&amp;soapAction=...`

Comment: Spring-ws throws WebServiceTransportException with &. Stacktrace below. 
2022-03-15 12:27:58.411 [http-nio-9090-exec-1   ] ERROR - null :: Exception occurred FQ :: 
org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceTransportException: Internal Server Error [500]
 at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.handleError(WebServiceTemplate.java:673)
 at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:591)
 at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:542)